# use DWM to distort a window under Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, aero, dwm

Windows 7 has in DWM function to distort a window. I am looking for information about how to use these functions (undocumented) to distort any window.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Are you asking whether such functions exist, or have you found such functions in a DLL and are looking for information about using them? If it is the latter, then can you specify the names of these functions and which DLLs they are present in?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way of doing this. I'm not even aware of an unsupported way of doing this. (If you manage to find one, make it clear to your customers that your program is doing unsupported things which can stop working at any time.)