# How do I do 3d manipulations on live windows 7 window contents?

Tags: windows, 3d, dwm

This is basically a scoping question, where would I look for the facility to render window contents to 3d surfaces and manipulate them? I mean can I have a program like a shell that composites live windows in 3d like the [Vista DWM's 3d Task Switcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx#S5) and can translate UI interactions back into 2d interactions for each window?

I've seen mention of DWM extensions here and there on the web but can't find any resources as to how that would work. Also there are guides to implementing DWM Thumbnails by relating two windows' HWNDs but that doesn't allow me to do arbitrary transforms on the window and is display only (you can't click on stuff in the thumbnail.)

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use DWM to distort a window under Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203862/use-dwm-to-distort-a-window-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no interface for manipulating the DWM's 3D visuals. They are internal to the DWM.